# Using function and if statement in SCSS

Tags: sass

I'm trying to make an if statement for scss key and value.

for example:

```
$directionLang: rtl;

@function rightOrLeft($directionLang) {
@if $directionLang == rtl {
  @return 'left: 10px';
}
@else {
  @return 'margin-left: 230px';
  }
}

.arrow-icon {
#{rightOrLeft($directionLang)};
}
```

The problem is inside the .arrow-icon.

I get an error:

> Error: property "#{rightOrLeft($directionLang)}" must be followed by a
>   ':'.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: As far as I know, you using function in a wrong way as it must be used on the right side of expression. With this syntax you should wirte and use mixin instead: `@include rightOrLeft(directionLang)`. More about functions you can find in Sass documentation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you should use SASS/SCSS `@mixin` instead of `@function`.

- `@function` in SASS/SCSS should be used to provide/calculate **value** e.g.

  ```
  .arrow-icon {
    margin-left: functionName(args);
  }
  ```
- `@mixin` is more powerful but also fits to your case when you want to get whole different css rules.

  Example snippet with your code:

  **HTML**

  ```
  <span class="arrow-icon">&larr;</span>
  ```

  **SCSS**

  ```
  $directionLang: rtl;
  //$directionLang: ltr;       //uncomment for test

  @mixin rightOrLeft($directionLang) {
     @if $directionLang == "rtl" {
        left: 10px;
     }  
     @else {
        margin-left: 230px;
     }
  }

  .arrow-icon {
     @include rightOrLeft($directionLang);
  }
  ```

  [Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/Bartosz/7aukmLft/12/)

Answer (score 0):

The functions are used to Get a value and you have to call them as value for your properties.

In your case you have to use mixin and include them in your class:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin